# Does function scope "lock" a value against changes made in asynchronous events and rapid successive function invocations?

Tags: javascript, scope, dom-events

On a portion of a web page, user options are provided though sets of radio buttons, check boxes, and input elements, and a change-event listener is placed on the parent containing all of the options.

The change-event handler builds an object of information necessary to undo/redo the option selections, pushes the most recent change to RAM as a function property, writes it to indexedDB, and, in the transaction oncomplete handler of the write request, logs a description of the change to an area of the document for the user to see, based on the data written to RAM as the property of a function.

If the user edits the value in an input element and, while it still has the focus, clicks a radio button, two change events fire, each invoking the same handler function of the parent's event listener.

The data written to RAM and indexedDB is recorded accurately, but if the user performs the click rapidly, the second change event updates the function property again before the first change event's write transaction completes, such that when the first event's log description is built from the most recent selection held in that function property, it uses the second event's data, resulting in two loggings to the DOM of the second event's selections.

To prevent this from occurring, an independent copy of the option-selection object is assigned to a variable declared locally in the change-event handler function, immediately after it has been built. It seems to be working, for I cannot reproduce what was taking place before no matter how quickly I attempt to click a radio button while an input element with an edit retains the focus.

My question is, does making the copy of the undo object guarantee that the oncomplete handler will always refer to that local function variable to build the log, even if a second change event updates the function property from which it was copied, and makes a new copy, before the oncomplete event fires? Is that local function's variable value "locked" in the function scope, such that the second invocation of it cannot alter what the oncomplete event of the first invocation uses to build the log?

Thank you.

After reading the answer from @Bergi, his use of "shared object" makes something clear to me, for my terminology was poor.

Since the shared object is an array of objects, where each object is data required for undo/redo, each change event needs to modify the shared object so the data is there for potential undo/redo. The issue is not that the second event is adding to the array while the first event's database write completes and before it references the last element in the array to build a log item. The issue is that the log item is always referencing the last object in the array. The undo object doesn't need to be cloned (for it's in RAM as a function property); instead, the array index needs stored in a local variable for reference to build the log from either the last element or the next-to-last element, when two change events take place in rapid succession.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Every function invocation creates its own local variables, and no code outside of its scope can access them. In your scenario, you also have to take care of not modifying shared objects but cloning them.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question. Please see my added comment to the question.

Comment: Ah, I see, you've got an append-only data structure, for which you only need to store the index up to which point it is considered valid. I was not sure what you meant with "function property".